# Do people in Britain use this structure nowdays? Or is it considered archaic there?

Tags: british-english, conditionals, archaicisms

I found it on one website about If I were/If I was usage, and I'm not sure it's common:

> If I had been a boy, I would have happily roamed outside all night.

“if I had been” talks about a particular instance, perhaps related to a context. For example:
“I saw all the boys chatting and enjoying themselves, starting at the moon from the stable. That’s when it struck me – If I had been a boy, I would have happily roamed outside all night too!”

Is it better just to use "If I were a boy, I would happily roam outside all night" even in particular instance?

Comment: _Had I been a boy, I would have_ ....... is, I would say, more colloquial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If I had been a boy, I would have happily roamed outside all night.

This is perfectly correct but, in conversation, we would be more likely to say, "If I'd been a boy, I would have happily roamed outside all night."

If you want to use "were" correctly then you would have to say "If I were to have been a boy ..." or "Were I to have been a boy ..." but these are old-fashioned.

---

**Notes**

1. There are many possible variations, for example, "If I'd been a boy, I'd have happily roamed outside all night." In this case, the first "I'd" means "I had" and the second "I'd" is an abbreviation of "I would."
2. You might even hear, ""If I'd've been a boy, I'd've happily roamed outside all night", although this is grammatically dubious.
3. "If I were a boy, I would happily roam outside all night". This is present tense (subjunctive followed by conditional). It says what you would do now. The original sentence is past tense. It says what you would have done when you were younger.

Comment: Thanks a lot! So you mentioned inverted conditional, I will appreciate if you tell me if they (inverted conditionals) are archaic nowdays in everyday speach?
*Probably I made a mistake in the second sentence

Comment: @Ellen - They are rare in Britain nowadays. Maybe a politician would use them in Parliament during a formal speech. Apart from that, you are unlikely to see them except in formal writing.

Comment: I've added another note - see my answer.

Comment: Yeaaah, finally I know the answer:) I was really confused about this topic, now it's clear

Comment: @Ellen - Note that many native speakers are not aware of these grammatical distinctions.  I was taught them at school and, as a child, I used to read a lot of the old classic novels where this sort of language was used.  In common speech it is quite common to hear the version I gave in example 2, although I would argue it is not correct.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, that is a normal construction to me.

It is effectively the past of *If I were a boy*.

*If I were a boy, I would roam...* is a counterfactual in the present. *If I had been a boy, I would have roamed...* is counterfactual in the past.

Just as with past perfects in general, it is optional when the temporal relationships are clear without it, and I suspect that some people would use it less than others.

I also find the mixed form *If I were a boy, I would have roamed...* to be natural: the past infinitive in the apodosis makes the time clear, so the past perfect in the protasis is optional.

Comment: It seems to me that both "mixed" forms (1: *If I were a boy, I would have roamed* and 2: *If I had been a boy, I would roam*) are potentially fine with their respective "strict" interpretations. In #1 I'm saying that if the "present counterfactual" were true, that "version of me who ***doesn't*** exist" would have a ***past*** within which I roamed, whereas in #2 I'm saying that if that "past counterfactual" version of me had been true, the ***current*** me would ***now*** be roaming.

Comment: Yes, I think I agree, @FumbleFingers; but I think my interpretation, where the protasis is by implication in the past, is also possible. I'm not sure there are any cases where the two interpretations can be distinguished.

Comment: It's interesting that OP thinks *If I **had been*** might be falling out favour though. Lots of native speakers don't know or don't care about his suggested alternative *If I **were***, so they just use *If I **was***. But practically every native speaker is clear about the difference between ***had been*** and ***were/was*** here, even if they're not clear about which one of that second pair to use.

Comment: It's too early in my day to think of a context where the two (both credible to me as well) interpretations of ***were + would have*** might be clearly distinguishable, but maybe someone else can think of one.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think the difference lies in whether the state is likely to have changed between the past and present. With the *boys* example, this is confused by the fact that the issue is gender, which hasn't changed, but boys don't remain boys.  *If I were there, I would have roamed*. The only contextually relevant sense is the past tense. One's location is subject to change. Compare to *If I were not agoraphobic, I would have roamed*.

Comment: I think this is actually a good example of a time where the two forms are **not** easily interchangeable. The character here is talking about *roaming* which is something to which  he would have been acclimated over time. It is not something that is solely forward-looking. The implication is that boys are raised from birth to *roam*. When saying *if I were*, the speaker is suggesting an immediate change, such as *If I were a boy, I could have short hair*.

Comment: @PhilSweet: *If I were not agoraphobic* (counterfactual *present*) could be followed by *...I would **have spent** more of my childhood outdoors* (in the "never existed" *past* of that counterfactual), OR by *...I would **spend** more of my time outdoors* (part of the "present counterfactual" scenario, the "hypothetical now").